Return raw text when accessed using GET requests
I made a script to get the user battery and put it as text, it has html, and when accessed using GET requests like the following:
requests.get("website").text
It return the source code but html only, same with roblox
game:HttpGet("website")
its originally set as .body.
It returns the source code of html only.
I've spent more than 10hrs on this project failing again and again. Help would be appreciated.
As in like raw.githubusercontent.com or just API thingy that just return plain text instead, I'm REALLY REALLY sorry because I'm just a beginner.
